# Use numpad to move+resize windows?

Tags: window-manager, resize

In my 16.10 I could use ctrl+alt+numpad to put a window into any half **or quarter** of the screen. Now that I've just wiped and **installed 19.10** this no longer works :-(

I want to use a modifier keyboard combo with the numpad so that modifier + Num9 would put the actice window into the top right quarter of my screen.

--> What can I do in order to use the numpad to move+resize a window?

*The [official documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-windows-states.html.en) is useless. Similar questions on this site are from 2011-2014.*

Comment: It looks like it might, yes. It requires me to re-login which I am not able to do in the middle of work. Does anyone know why this is not included in Ubuntu by default?

Comment: No idea but Put Windows Gnome Shell Extension works well for me and I'm sure it will for you too. Don't forget the change over from Unity to Gnome will have influenced this. Shall I post this as an answer to your question?

Comment: Yes, please do. I hope to reboot my computer sometime this weekend.